# MySql - Delete duplicate rows, without temp Table

Tags: mysql

I have this table **email_addr_bean_rel** with these fields`id, email_address_id, bean_id, bean_module, primary_address, reply_to_address, date_created, date_modified, deleted`

Out of these only records of column **bean_id** is duplicated twice.

I have tried this, but it doesn't work

```
CREATE TABLE email_addr_bean_rel_V AS SELECT DISTINCT * FROM email_addr_bean_rel;
DROP TABLE email_addr_bean_rel;
RENAME TABLE email_addr_bean_rel_V TO email_addr_bean_rel;
```

It still contains same number of records.

Comment: You are taking the distinct condition on *, which will always give distinct, you should try with bean_id to get distinct

Comment: Yup..got it
CREATE TABLE email_addr_bean_rel_V  AS SELECT * FROM email_addr_bean_rel WHERE 1 GROUP BY bean_id;